# CSS how to center table

Tags: css, center, css-tables

I'm finishing set up a WordPress site to my client but I am facing a little issue ion contact page.

I cannot center the table with phone number and email...

http://asepticservices.fr/fr/contact/

I tried with `margin:auto;
text-align : center` on table selector but It never moves from left to center during my test in Chrome inspector...

Any idea to help me ?

Below picture shows how it looks actually. I would like the numbers and mail to be centered

[image]

Comment: Could you specify (maybe through screenshot or other) what is the final result you are finding?

Comment: Hi, sur ! I edited my post to add a screenshot

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Remove `display: block;` from your class .aligncenter and thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have this result adding `text-align: center` on the parent `table` and then `display: inline-block` in the `tbody`.

[image]

Keep in mind that `text-align` will apply aligning of the `inline` and `inline-block` displayed elements.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the note about text-align

Answer (score 1):

The `align` attribute can help you directly in the html.

In your html, you can replace this :

```
<table class=" aligncenter" style="height: 89px;" width="192">
<!-- The table -->
</table>
```

by this :

```
<table style="height: 89px;" width="192" align="center">
<!-- The table -->
</table>
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

you have a css rule applying to all tables on the document:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

You need overwrite the width rule to auto on the "wpb_wrapper" class

```
.wpb_wrapper table{width: 250px} /*or the value that you want*/
```

Hope this could be useful.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the table's width from the table's tag.
2. wrap this table inside a div.
3. assign the following CSS to that div:

   .div_class {
       width: 230px; /* Or any suitable width for you */
       display: block;
       margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Apply this style to the class aligncenter:

```
.aligncenter {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and also this to tbody

```
tbody
{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```